# $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R -\{0\}$, but cannot be made into a continuous function by change on a set of measure zero.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, lebesgue-measure, alternative-proof

Consider $f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \ge 0\\ 0 & x < 0\end{cases} $$
$f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R -\{0\}$, but cannot be made into a continuous function by change on a set of measure zero.

since there exists dense set of  irrational numbers after removing a set of measure zero ,i can show there exists $(x_n),(y_n)$ of irrational number converges to 0, but $(f(x_n)) $ converges to 0 and $(f(y_n))$ converges to 1.Therefore, this function is discontinous at x=0(I didn't add explicit sequence but is this idea of proof correct)

Comment: It is not even remotely true that all negative irrationals are zero. For your actual question: zero has nothing to do with it, in fact (and neither do irrationals): this is an entirely topological fact: the function is just two lines which don't join up.

Comment: You talk of "this idea of proof" but I don't see an idea. All you said is "I think the problem occurs at 0". This is not an idea of proof, since nothing you have said sheds any light on how to argue.

Comment: Again, there is no argument. Obviously the function is discontinuous. So what? You have not yet begun to address the question. By the way, you accepted the answer you were given, but there is some serious work still required to turn it into a full answer, and I am not sure you know yet how, given the level of confusion your suggested attempt indicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is, at least, incomplete. You don't explain why, after removing a set with measure $0$, you can always find such a sequence of irrational numbers.

I think that the introduction of irrational numbers in this problem is not the best approach. All you need is to use the fact if $A\subset\mathbb R$ has measure $0$, then $A^\complement$ is dense.